# Knockout Observable not updating on Modal DOM/UI

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

Knockout observable value not updating on bootstrap Modal. In debug I can see that the value have been successfully added to observable. It just not updating/appearing on the modal DOM.

```
self.getSdsById = function (val) {
        var ID = val.ID;
        var operation = event.currentTarget.dataset['operation'];
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/SdsView/getSdsByID',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { 'ID': ID },
            success: function (data) {
                self.CopySdsDetail().RegistrationNo(data.Sds.RegistrationNo);
                self.CopySdsDetail().MSDSIssueDate(data.Sds.MSDSIssueDate);
                self.CopySdsDetail().Place(data.Sds.Place);
                self.CopySdsDetail().Dept(data.Sds.Dept);
                self.CopySdsDetail().Div(data.Sds.Div);

                if (operation == 'COPY') {
                    $('#copyModalTitle').text('Copy & Add SDS to other Division');
                    $('#copyModal').modal();
                }
            }
        }).fail(
            function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                swal("Error", err, "error");
            });
    }
```

Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="copyModal">
    <div class="table-responsive" data-bind="with: CopySdsDetail">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
        <tr>
            <td>Division: </td>
            <td>Department: </td>
            <td>Place: </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Div"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Dept"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Place"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: RegistrationNo" colspan="2"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: MSDSIssueDate"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ko observable value in debug:

[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

in the short time I had to look at this, it generally looks ok, I got a very basic sample working with what you have provided.  maybe it will help

```js
var data = {
  Dept: "Dicing",
  Div: "DCG",
  ID: 0,
  MSDSIssueDate: "/Date(1602172800000)/",
  Place: "Etching Process",
  RegistrationNo: "DS-033"
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.CopySdsDetail = ko.observable(new ModalViewModel());
  self.clearData = function(){
    self.CopySdsDetail(new ModalViewModel());
  }
  self.getData = function() {
    self.CopySdsDetail(new ModalViewModel(data));
//    self.CopySdsDetail().RegistrationNo(data.RegistrationNo);
//    self.CopySdsDetail().MSDSIssueDate(data.MSDSIssueDate);
//    self.CopySdsDetail().Place(data.Place);
//    self.CopySdsDetail().Dept(data.Dept);
//    self.CopySdsDetail().Div(data.Div);
  }
}

function ModalViewModel(data){
  var self = this;
  data = data || {};
  self.RegistrationNo = ko.observable(data.RegistrationNo || "");
  self.Dept = ko.observable(data.Dept || "");
  self.Div = ko.observable(data.Div || "");
  self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID || "");
  self.MSDSIssueDate = ko.observable(data.MSDSIssueDate || "");
  self.Place = ko.observable(data.Place || "");
}


var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="copyModal">
  <div class="table-responsive" data-bind="with: CopySdsDetail">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
      <tr>
        <td>Division: </td>
        <td>Department: </td>
        <td>Place: </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Div" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Dept" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Place" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: RegistrationNo" colspan="2"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: MSDSIssueDate"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: getData">Get Data</button>
<button data-bind="click: clearData">Clear Data</button>
```